# put a more positive spin on

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> For Kant, feelings simply cloud the issue, making it more difficult to
>   see that someone is genuinely doing the right thing, rather than just
>   seeming to. Or to **put a more positive spin on this**: Kant **made morality**
>   **available to every rational person**, whether or not they were fortunate
>   enough to have feelings that motivated them to act well.

What does "put a more positive spin on this" mean?

and I don't understand the expression "**Kant made morality available to every rational person**" Is it right to say "Kant supplied every rational person with morality"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "put a more positive spin on this" mean?

It means, to turn it in a more positive way, to present it like something more positive.

> "Kant made morality available to every rational person" Is it right to say "Kant supply every rational person with morality"?

No. It means that anyone can have access to morality, that morality isn't something accessible only by a certain group of people.